# ncurses (terminal emulator) unicode unreliable subscripts?

Tags: c++, unicode, ncurses

I added ncursesw support for my little project and I can now output all kinds of unicode characters to the terminal emulator ("terminator" or "gnome-teminal").

The problem is that some, but not all, alphabetical subscripts come out as spaces!
The problem subscripts are:

`h,k,l,m,n,p,s,t` (a contiguous block from `\u2095` to `\u209C`)

Subscripts `a,e,i,j,u,v` display correctly.

The terminal emulator CAN display these characters when sufficiently informed, as evinced by the output of a command like

`echo -e '\u2095'`

These characters can even be "pasted into" the terminal, but only directly to the command line and NOT via programs like nano, which makes me suspect ncurses.

Can these subscripts be displayed??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends: [according to Unicode.org](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=2095), those characters were added in 6.0 and may not appear in all fonts, and also their information may not appear in the locale tables.  ncurses uses the locale tables; a character without information will be displayed as a blank.

Although [6.0 was released a few years ago](http://unicode.org/history/publicationdates.html), it's not uncommon for vendors to take several years to do updates for non-critical features such as this.

Terminal emulators don't necessarily use the locale tables (except to handle the special cases of double-width and combining-characters), so it's possible to see a "normal" (but new) character displayed using `cat` (which does **not** use locale), but not with applications such as a text-editor.